# Win32 GetSaveFileName() return is nonzero but file isnt saved?

Tags: c, visual-studio, winapi, win32gui

I am currently setting up an Editor using Win32 as a challenge for myself but my Method for saving the file for some reason doesnt save the file. I checked multiple times with my resources and looked over threads on the internet but I either didnt have the problem that got solved there in the first place or it didnt help at all. Am I overseeing something here?

```
void SaveUserFile(HWND hwnd)
{
    OPENFILENAME ofn;
    char szFile[MAX_PATH] = "";

    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
    ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
    ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;
    ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
    ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
    ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
    ofn.lpstrFilter = TEXT("Text document(*.txt*)\0*.txt\0Word 2016 document(*.docx*)\0*.docx\0All Files(*.*)\0*.*\0");
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
    ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
    ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
    ofn.lpstrDefExt = "mp";
    ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY;

    GetSaveFileName(&ofn);
}
```

Comment: What contents do you expect the system to write to the file? And how do you propose the system would know about your expectations?

Comment: Hi, does the answer solve your issue? Please feel free to let me know if you have any issue and also accept it if it does help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetSaveFileName` does not save a file. It shows a dialog which allows the user to select a file name. If this returns successfully the program must then write the code to save the file, using the file name provided by the user which the program can read in `szFile`.

In new programs you should use the [common item dialogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/bb776913(v=vs.85)) ([`IFileOpenDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifileopendialog) and [`IFileSaveDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifilesavedialog)) rather than `GetOpenFileName` and `GetSaveFileName`. There are numerous reasons for this, but one of the most obvious is that you will not be limited in file name length.

Comment: `IFileOpenDialog` and `IFileSaveDialog` are C++ methods, the OP is programming in plain C seems.

Comment: @fra Both interfaces are COM interfaces. COM is language-agnostic. The only two language-level requirements COM places on clients are: `1` Must be able to produce structures of pointers. `2` Must be able to call functions through pointers, directly or indirectly. C matches those requirements.

Comment: @IInspectable Both are COM interfaces, but in `GetSaveFileName` COM interface is handled transparently to the user in the `Comdlg32.dll`, while the  common item dialogs need specific initialization. While COM interface can be also handled in plain C, many compilers for C only can't use, or don't have, COM support headers. In that case the former functions are the obvious and effective solution.

Comment: @Frankie_C It's true that for many needs the legacy functions are fine. But if you've ever implemented a multi-select file open dialog, you'll not want to use them, unless you are happy with the restriction on how many files can be selected at once.

Comment: @fra A C compiler doesn't need any specific COM support headers. COM support is built right into the core language, and the Windows SDK headers expose the C structures if you request them. Likewise, COM doesn't need any particular initialization. Threads need to be registered into the correct apartment, sure, but that needs to be done in *any* language, like C++.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan sure you can't afford a complex interface with old legacy functions.

Comment: @IInspectable that's true only for MS compilers and few others that aren't standard compatible (MS has always been not standard). Many small plain ISO-C compatible compilers don't mix standard and proprietary behaviors. Try to use `CoCreateInstance` with a compiler able to use COM's on plain C bases, and it will immediately complain for CLD_ID's passed for value and not for reference (MS does conversions under the hood).

Comment: @fra Not sure which COM you are referring to, but Microsoft's COM is 100% C compliant and works with *any* confirming C compiler. I don't know what a "CLD_ID" is, or how you would pass a reference to one in C.

Comment: @IInspectable In C passing by reference means passing a pointer to a variable, but don't mind.

Comment: @fra Still doesn't explain what a "CLD_ID" is, or which specific aspect of COM you believe to be inaccessible from Standard C. And, you know, that appears to be the point you have been struggling to drive home, right?

Comment: @IInspectable Sorry I meant `IID`. Consider the MS sample https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/example--the-open-dialog-box, the code `hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOpenDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IFileOpenDialog, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pFileOpen));` to be used in C must be `hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOpenDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IFileOpenDialog, (void**)(&pFileOpen));`. This under MSVC will compile, but not on other C compilers, that require `hr = CoCreateInstance(&CLSID_FileOpenDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, &IID_IFileOpenDialog, (void**)(&pFileOpen));`.

Comment: @IInspectable  Even if everything will work at the end more or less this require skills that aren't always available for C.

Comment: @fra Er... So you found sample code, that's non-standard C, and you somehow turn that to mean, that COM cannot (or at least not easily) be used with C? Mind to elaborate on that, because, you know, I'm having a hard time following along.

Comment: @IInspectable I told you don't mind. It's a waste of time.

Comment: Who is really involved will understand.